# How to form this sql query in order to check for multiple specific values without causing duplicates?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following table with these columns: `the_comment_liked`, `user_who_liked`, `value`.

I set up an [SQL fidle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be1aec1/3).

And this is part of the query that I use:

```
SELECT the_comment_liked,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN value = '1' then '1' ELSE NULL END) AS tot_like,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN value = '2' then '1' ELSE NULL END) AS tot_dis,
    GROUP_CONCAT(user_who_liked) AS user_who_liked
FROM like_dislike_comm
GROUP BY the_comment_liked
```

Now I perform a `PHP` check to see if the user has liked or disliked like this:

```
 if (strpos($r_com['user_who_liked'] ,$_SESSION["currentUser"]) !== false){//set a variable}
 //$_SESSION["currentUser"] (this stores the id of the current logged user)
```

If this returns true I set a class to a variable in order to highlight the like or dislike button, the problem is that I also have to check for the value in order to know if it's a like or a dislike, something like:

```
 if (strpos($r_com['user_who_liked'] ,$_SESSION["currentUser"]) !== false && $r_com['value'] === 1){}
```

Now I can do that by selecting the value as well, but that gives me duplicates.
How can I form the query in order to check not only if the user id is there but also the value, a like or a dislike? Or in what other ways I could perform a check like this?

I need to have everything grouped so I can display the total amount of likes and dislikes on a comment and at the same time, I need for each `user_who_liked` to check if the `value` is an `1`(like) or a `2`(dislike) so I can highlight the like or dislike button on each comment in order for the logged user to see what he liked or not. I'm also not sure that using `GROUP_CONCAT(user_who_liked)` is the right approach.

*Mysql version is 5.7.14*

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to check. Do you need to check if the user liked something?

Comment: @clinomaniac yes, when a user likes or dislikes i insert his id into the database, 1 means like and 2 means dislike and then i need to check the `value` to see which one is it so i can "color" the like or dislike button, but because everything is grouped i don't know how to check what that user who is logged in did (liked or disliked)

Comment: Can you show what you expect to see from the query as output? What do you need to pass to the query besides user_id?

Comment: @clinomaniac I'm not sure, i somehow need for each user that liked or disliked to check the `value` but since everything is grouped i don't know what value belongs to what user. I used `GROUP_CONCAT(user_who_liked)` to see if a user did something at all but im not sure that's the right approach, i need to know exactly if it's an `1`or a `2`.

Comment: What are you trying to check? I am still not clear. `i somehow need for each user that liked or disliked to check the value` That's the data in the table. Each user with the value. `i need to know exactly if it's an 1or a 2`. What is `it`?

Comment: @clinomaniac So this is part of a bigger query i use for comments, i use this table to store like/dislikes for the comments, when  a user click's like i insert a `1` if he click's dislike i insert a `2` in the `value` column.  Now i want to highlight the like or dislike button depending on this `value`. This `value` is what i need to check for every user

Comment: Why do you need to know the `value` for EVERY user?  It seems like you are more concerned with the current user.  It seems like you are going to need two queries -- one that will get the total number of likes or dislikes regardless of who clicked it, and a second that gets the `value` for the current user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know how to do conditional aggregations (`COUNT(CASE ..)`). To find the `value` of the current user per comment, you just need one more. Assuming the ID of current user is `118`, it would be something like:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN user_who_liked = 118 THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS value_of_current_user
```

It doesn't matter if you use `MAX` or `MIN` here, since there should be only one value. You can even use `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Note that `NULL` is default value for the `ELSE` case, so you can omit it:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN user_who_liked = 118 THEN value END) AS value_of_current_user
```

You can also write it a bit shorter:

```
MAX(CASE user_who_liked WHEN 118 THEN value END) AS value_of_current_user
```

So your final query could be:

```
SELECT the_comment_liked,
    COUNT(CASE value WHEN 1 then 1 END) AS tot_like,
    COUNT(CASE value WHEN 2 then 1 END) AS tot_dis,
    GROUP_CONCAT(user_who_liked) AS user_who_liked,
    MAX(CASE user_who_liked WHEN 118 THEN value END) AS value_of_current_user
FROM like_dislike_comm
GROUP BY the_comment_liked
```

[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be1aec1/21)

If you also whant to split the ID list into `users_who_liked` and `users_who_disliked`, you can use conditional aggregation for `GROUP_CONCAT` too:

```
SELECT the_comment_liked,
    COUNT(CASE value WHEN 1 then 1 END) AS tot_like,
    COUNT(CASE value WHEN 2 then 1 END) AS tot_dis,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE value WHEN 1 THEN user_who_liked END) AS user_who_liked,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE value WHEN 2 THEN user_who_liked END) AS user_who_disliked,
    MAX(CASE user_who_liked WHEN 118 THEN value END) AS value_of_current_user
FROM like_dislike_comm
GROUP BY the_comment_liked
```

[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be1aec1/23)

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstand something, each time you run this query, it's likely for only one user (the one logged in).

If this is the case, then it's pretty inefficient to have your SQL not help you out more.

The solution below is hard-coded for user 118.  Your PHP should inject this parameter where you see 118, OR, you can turn this code into a MySQL stored procedure that takes the user as a parameter.

The output shows all comments, the total likes, total dislikes, and what the vote for that one user is (1 = like, 2 = dislike, null = no vote).

```
select
  totals.the_comment_liked,
  totals.tot_like,
  totals.tot_dis,
  like_or_dislike.value as this_users_vote
from
  (
    select
      the_comment_liked,
      sum(case when value = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as tot_like,
      sum(case when value = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as tot_dis
    from
      like_dislike_comm
    group by
      the_comment_liked
  ) as totals
  left outer join (
    select 
      the_comment_liked,
      value
    from
      like_dislike_comm
    where
      /* This value has to be dynamically inserted by your PHP, 
         OR you can make this a parameter in a stored procedure */
      user_who_liked = 118 
  ) as like_or_dislike on
    totals.the_comment_liked = like_or_dislike.the_comment_liked
```

This returns the following result set (again, this is hard-coded for user 118):

```
the_comment_liked   tot_like    tot_dis this_users_vote
310 0   1   2
311 1   1   1
312 1   2   2
313 1   2   1
314 0   3   2
315 2   1   2
339 1   0   (null)
340 1   0   (null)
341 1   0   (null)
347 1   0   (null)
353 1   0   (null)
360 1   1   2
365 0   1   (null)
366 1   1   (null)
370 1   2   1
378 1   0   (null)
380 1   0   (null)
387 2   0   (null)
388 1   0   (null)
394 1   1   (null)
395 0   1   (null)
426 1   0   (null)
430 2   0   (null)
439 0   1   (null)
```